# Installing CUDA Windows 10

Tags: windows, cuda, data-science, driver

I am trying to install the CUDA toolkit in order to be able to use Thundersvm in my personal computer.
However I keep getting the following message in the GUI installer:
"You already have a newer version of the NVIDIA Frameview SDK installed"

I read in the CUDA forums that this most probably results from having installed Geforce Experience (which I have installed). So I tried removing it from the Programs and Features windows panel. However I still got the error, so my guess is that the "Nvidia Corporation" folder was not removed.

In the same question, they also suggested performing a custom install. However I could not find any information on how to do a custom install of the CUDA toolkit. I would really appreciate if someone could explain how to do this custom install or safely remove the previous drivers. I thought of using DDU but I read that sometimes it may actually lead to trouble.

Comment: In a generic install, the toolkit should be under C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit. Alternatively, perhaps you can look in the registry with regedit. If CUDA *IS* properly installed, you should see an entry in "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\NVIDIA Corporation\GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA"

Comment: Hello. I tried both ways and could find the GPU computing toolkit. For more context when I start the CUDA installer it starts checking if the system if compatible and then it says it can not continue with the installation because I already have a newer version of NVIDIA frameview, it does not give any choice on what packages to install. I read you could perform a custom install by extracting only folders of interest. I inspected the contents with 7-zip but don't know which folders to extract.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I had the same problem while I was trying to get TensorFlow to use my NVIDIA GTX1070 GPU for calculations. Here's what allowed me to perform the CUDA Toolkit installation on my Windows 10 machine.

As the error message in the installer says - you already have a newer Frameview SDK installed. It was the case for me.

1. Go to *Settings/Uninstall or modify programs*.
2. Remove the *NVIDIA Frameview* program. It should be there with GeForce Experience, PhysX, etc.

Uninstalling only this NVIDIA program didn't cause any driver problems for my machine and I was able to progress through the CUDA Toolkit installation.

Comment: Future reference for anyone who can't get Tensorflow to recognize GPUs: you must follow their instructions *to the letter*. NVIDIA driver must be 450 or higher, CUDA toolkit must be precisely 11.0, cuDNN SDK must be precisely 8.0.4, and most importantly: use pip install tensorflow. If you're using Conda, you can activate the environment then conda install pip.

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu
Here's the table for each TensorFlow version. The last digit of the version does not matter. However as David stated `cuDNN` and `CUDA` must match precisely.

Answer (score 0):

I just met the same problem and fixed it now.
This problem occurred because you chose the default installation configuration, which might contain many installed parts. In my situation, I have installed NVIDIA Nsight Compute, which is the culprit during the first few installs.

Unchecking the redundant parts should be helpful.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32278560)